# Best way to specify nested dict with pydantic?

Tags: python, validation, nested, fastapi, pydantic

### Context

I'm trying to validate/parse some data with `pydantic`.

I want to specify that the dict can have a key `daytime`, or not.
If it does, I want the value of `daytime` to include both `sunrise` and `sunset`.

e.g. These should be allowed:

```
{
   'type': 'solar',
   'daytime': {
      'sunrise': 4, # 4am
      'sunset': 18 # 6pm
   }
}
```

And

```
{
   'type': 'wind'
   # daytime key is omitted
}
```

And

```
{
   'type': 'wind',
   'daytime': None
}
```

But I want to fail validation for

```
{
   'type': 'solar',
   'daytime': {
      'sunrise': 4
   }
}
```

Because this has a `daytime` value, but no sunset value.

### MWE

I've got some code that does this.
If I run this script, it executes successfully.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError
from typing import List, Optional, Dict

class DayTime(BaseModel):
    sunrise: int
    sunset: int
    
class Plant(BaseModel):
    daytime: Optional[DayTime] = None
    type: str

p = Plant.parse_obj({'type': 'wind'})
p = Plant.parse_obj({'type': 'wind', 'daytime': None})
p = Plant.parse_obj({
    'type': 'solar', 
    'daytime': {
        'sunrise': 5, 
        'sunset': 18
    }})
    
try:
    p = Plant.parse_obj({
        'type': 'solar', 
        'daytime': {
            'sunrise': 5
        }})
except ValidationError:
    pass
else:
    raise AssertionError("Should have failed")
```

### Question

What I'm wondering is,
**is this how you're supposed to use pydantic for nested data?**

I have lots of layers of nesting, and this seems a bit verbose.

Is there any way to do something more concise, like:

```
class Plant(BaseModel):
    daytime: Optional[Dict[('sunrise', 'sunset'), int]] = None
    type: str
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pydantic [`create_model`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation) function is what you need:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model

class Plant(BaseModel):
    daytime: Optional[create_model('DayTime', sunrise=(int, ...), sunset=(int, ...))] = None
    type: str
```

Comment: is there any way to leave it untyped? Just say dict of dict?

Comment: @Nickpick You can simply declare dict as the type for daytime if you didn't want further typing, like so: `daytime: dict`

Comment: How is this different from the questioner's MWE? I can't see the advantage of `create_model('DayTime', ...)` over `class DayTime(BaseModel): ...`. The docs only say that `create_model()` is for when the shape of a model is not known until runtime.

Comment: I'd rather avoid this solution at least for OP's case, it's harder to understand, and still 'flat is better than nested'

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```py
class DayTime(BaseModel):
    sunrise: int
    sunset: int
    
class Plant(BaseModel):
    daytime: Optional[DayTime] = None
    type: str

yo_data  = {
    'type': 'solar', 
    'daytime': {
        'sunrise': 5, 
        'sunset': 18
    }}

# then simply

a_plant = Plant(**yo_data)

[see](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/#pydantic-examples)
```